# Uninstall lubuntu and Install Windows 10

Tags: windows, lubuntu

I wanted to install lubuntu on my Windows 10 as dual boot, but unfortunately my windows 10 got replaced by lubuntu. Now I can't install windows 10 using USB or DVD as when I try, it directly takes me to lubuntu screen. I formatted using live lubuntu (gparted) but now it's giving me an grub error (unknown file format)
Tried every possible way, but no success.
Any advice??

Comment: Set it to Boot from USB in the CMOS.

Comment: Can you exactly tell us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

When your computer starts booting it should tell you which key to press to enter a menu where you can choose which media to boot from, normally a <kbd>FN</kbd> (where **N** is a number like <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>) key or <kbd>ESC</kbd>. Choose to boot from your DVD or USB here.

When you have formatted your disk, you also have removed the files that GRUB tries to load.